# Using "node" to initialize scripts does not work while "nodejs" does

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I followed [installation instructions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) and successfully installed on a Ubuntu machine. But when I try to check the version with command `node -v`, it doesn't return anything but when I enter `nodejs -v` it gives out the version. Ditto with the execution of scripts, if I give `node hello.js` nothing happens but when I give `nodejs hello.js`, the file executes.

I checked online on various websites and everywhere they are using node and not nodejs. I checked with a friend who has also installed from the same location and even for her its running with node and when she tries to give nodejs it says command not found. I also didnt find any documented issue regarding this. Any help is appreciated.

I just want to confirm is the below the reason for the problem?

> There is a naming conflict with the node package (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program), and the nodejs binary has been renamed from node to nodejs. You'll need to symlink /usr/bin/node to /usr/bin/nodejs or you could uninstall the Amateur Packet Radio Node Program to avoid that conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a known problem. You can read about that [here](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/07/msg00002.html), and the issue is also posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4772).

From Debian.org in response:

> The nodejs package shall be changed to provide /usr/bin/nodejs, not
>      /usr/bin/node.  The package shall declare a Breaks: relationship with any
>      packages in Debian that reference /usr/bin/node.